# Cannot sign in to Microsoft Account (Cortana) using Win10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account, cortana

I've just upgraded to Win10, and I am trying to sign into my Microsoft Account in order to use Cortana, however I am caught in a loop and it won't accept my credentials.

The credentials are definitely right, verified by accessing the Microsoft account via https://account.microsoft.com. Also, if I type my credentials incorrectly when trying to sign in on my PC I am told the credentials are wrong - therefore I can be certain that the authentication process is taking place.

Steps are as follows:

- Start
- Type "Your Account"
- Enter
- Scroll down on the Setting window
- "Add a Microsoft account"
- Enter email and password (for Microsoft account)
- Sign in

Nothing happens. I am returned to the previous screen and not logged in.

The same is true when I place my cursor in the bottom left hand corner search bar. I am asked to sign in to be able to use Cortana, the dialogues about getting you to sign in just go round in a loop after I've entered my credentials.

Comment: So you have connected your local account to your Microsoft Account correct?  Do you use two-factor authentication on your Microsoft Account?

Comment: My local account is successfully connected (when I log into my laptop with that) - but it's my work PC and we're on a domain, so I use my domain account to sign into my laptop - this isn't connecting to my Microsoft account...

Comment: Your domain administrator may have disabled the ability to associate a Microsoft account with a domain account. ([Relevant TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj966262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Comment: Indeed.  If it is failing to connect, it's likely because, it's failing to even attempt the login

Comment: Don't know if this is related, but can't hurt to check.  Microsoft has recently been having some strange user account corruption problems.  Try deleting all Microsoft-related cookies you can identify in your browser and restart the browser.  I found that it triggered some kind of reset on Microsoft's side that cleared up the problem.

Comment: I have spoken to our domain administrator, and there is no disablement going on. He did have the theory that the local account on my machine is a Microsoft Account and this would likely conflict with the process. I have now removed that local account (which was a Microsoft Account) but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer from information posted by another user on the TechNet forum. Here is the link: [Can't sign in to Microsoft Account](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70a5d9ad-0f4f-4ed8-b000-59927db4b0de/cant-sign-in-to-microsoft-account?forum=win10itprogeneral).

I jumped straight to Step 4 in the reply marked as 'Solved', which was this:

> Edit your registry
>
> HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities
>
> Here, you will see the account that is giving you trouble.  Delete
>   (right click the email address and click Delete).
>
> Settings, Accounts, add your Microsoft account back in.

Comment: In the registry when I go to `HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities`
 I can only See `Default REG_SZ (value not set)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me :) My email was listed as you said it would be.

Comment: I can only see `Default REG_SZ (value not set)`