# Can't sign in to Windows 10 with Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, regedit, microsoft-account

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/949904):

> Edit your registry
>
> HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities
>
> Here, you will see the account that is giving you trouble. Delete
>   (right click the email address and click Delete).
>
> Settings, Accounts, add your Microsoft account back in.

But it only shows me "Default REG_SZ (Value not set). What exactly am I deleting here? Did I miss a step somehow? Is it safe to delete the Default entity seen here?

Comment: Do a registry backup of your default settings and change as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: I hope people are not so quick to close this as a duplicate.  The accepted answer to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/948319/cannot-sign-in-to-microsoft-account-cortana-using-win10/949904#949904) question has apparently not helped multiple people.  There is something else going on in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you to delete the email of the microsoft account that the system has stored. It's safe to delete it, and if the thing tells you that it's not set yet, skip that step and go ahead adding your microsoft account in the control panel.